# CI/CD for Apache Spark on K8s applications - how to do it effeciently?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, kubernetes

I'm looking for advice on how to do **resource efficient** CI/CD process for Apache Spark applications when it comes to running them in Spark on K8s mode - basically how to have it all in k8s native fashion.

Background: I have hadoop + application artifact with dependencies packaged in giant 4 GB image. Generally speaking anytime I need to deploy new version of my application I have to update this 4 GB image this way forcing any compute node on K8s cluster when my container luckily ends up there to pull this image blob into its cache registry. Cluster is large, thousands of nodes, so this introduces quite a load on every single compute node. I also have thousands of containers like this running daily. I can't shrink this image further (I was given one by vendor and asked to use as is).

Among the options I have been able to discover (all considered in addition to static Hadoop-only image without business code):

- Store application on same storage where data will be processed (Hadoop, S3, etc) - I don't want to expose my business code there as its multi-tenant environment.
- Store application on external HTTPS exposed registry - I haven't tried it yet, but its next on my list
- Store application in own mini docker image that contains just business jars then run it in combination with hadoop image in sidecar - I found it inefficient memory-wise and slow because I can't access filesystem of sidecar container directly. I have to copy it to shared workdir volume as workaround, but then: for Disk mode - this operation is slow, for Memory mode - very memory expensive for large application like mine.
- Store application on k8s PersistentVolumeClaim then read it from hadoop-only containers - what I'm using right now, but feels wrong since it introduces state what k8s is strongly against. I want to move away from it.

Essentially, I need an efficient process to deliver application to some centralized spot and share it with containers of spark on k8s that my scheduler is running, yet Spark docs don't explicitly mention how to do it efficiently. Am I missing something some part of puzzle? How do people run hadoop apps at scale without breaking a buck on network?
Disclaimer - its all in context of opensource software only.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been using Argo Workflows as an orchestrator for spark jobs on k8s.

The way I set it up is:

- One CI/CD pipeline that is only responsible to build docker image of my code and publish it to an artifactory.
- Another CI/CD pipeline that deploys my Argo objects which can either be WorkflowTemplates or CronWorkflows. The same pipeline can also deploy cleanup jobs that periodically delete driver pods. These cleanup jobs are native k8s CronJobs.